# Getting "Play To" working on Windows 8 and a Playstation 3

Tags: windows-8, dlna, ps3

On Windows 8, "Play To" functionality has been integrated into Windows Explorer;

[image]

However, as you can see, "Play To" is disabled; and I don't know why.

When I hover over the option, I get no information.

If I do things the other way round (set my PC as the streaming server through Windows Media Player, and then search for my PC from the PS3) this works fine; but as I've got many hundreds of videos on my PC, I want to be able to select a video from my laptop, and stream *that* to my PS3 instead.

I was under the impression that:

- "Play To" works for any DLNA enabled device
- A PS3 is a DLNA enabled device

Sharing is turned **ON** for this network on my Windows 8 PC, and I've ensured (and proved via the alternate approach above) that the two devices can communicate.

If it's any help, I can't see the PS3 listed as a network device, nor can I see it when I search for devices.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Playstation 3 is not a Digital Media Renderer (DMR), which is what is required for PlayTo to work.

Whilst the Playstation 3 is DLNA certified, it is only a Digital Media Player (DMP), which means it can only pull content from media servers. Content can not be sent to it remotely.

For more information, see [this answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpromedia/thread/fefb5a3d-9a1d-4581-b5fe-f139cd378909) on the Microsoft Forums.

Answer (score 6):

I would assume you first have to *install* the PS3 as a playback device through the **Devices** application. Then it will become available in that dropdown menu.

The Windows help notes:

> If your Play To device isn't listed with your other devices on the Devices page, it might not be connected to the network. To check the Devices page, swipe in from the right edge of the screen (or if you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen and move the mouse pointer down), tap or click **Settings**, tap or click **Change PC Settings**, and then tap or click **Devices**.
>
> To fix problems with connecting your device to a network, see the info that came with your device.

I found a YouTube video of someone installing a [WDTV on Windows 8 through DLNA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oaGv47_7jrI).
As we can see, the device should come up in the **Devices** interface as a **Digital media renderer**:
[image]

### Other stuff to try out (most likely unrelated)

Also, please check if Media Streaming is enabled:
 
[image]

The [PlayStation 3 Media Center documentation](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/connectdlna.html) hints that Windows Media Player could be involved in this (but I doubt the text was written with Windows 8 in mind).

Comment: I think this may be where the problem lies; but I can't see my Playstation 3 in this list, and I can't find a way to get it to appear.

Comment: @Matt: Does it make a difference if you try to add it manually? Open the **Devices and Printers** desktop application, then click **Add a Device** in it.

Comment: Regarding the media streaming option. After testing a bit further, I don't think it has an impact on your situation. It seems to only apply to being able to use the device as a media source. When I enabled it on another computer on my network, it was instantly available for installation as a network media player on Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help `@`Oliver... I've now enabled Media Sharing, but it still doesn't work. The article you linked to on the PS3MCD seemed to be routing down the avenue of the alternate approach I mentioned (seeing the list of media on the PS3 and selecting which one you want to play)... where-as I want to be able to choose some media on my laptop and "Play it to" my PS3 directly...

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, I realize that as well now. The PS3 should identify itself as a digital media renderer. Those can then be used through the Play To functionality. If the PS3 does not identify itself like that, maybe it's a connectivity issue or there's actually some sort of incompatibility I am not yet aware of.

Comment: @Matt: Just FYI. I installed [UPnPlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cx.hoohol.silanoid) on my SGS2 and (after enabling the renderer) it showed up right away in the Devices list for me to install on Windows 8. Afterwards, the Play To option was enabled (and worked as expected).